# How to use NMinimize with a large scale of variables?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I can only write like this:

```
NMinimize[
  {GoalFunction[graph, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12}], 
  cons[graph, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12}, 2500],
  x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0, x5 > 0, x6 > 0, x7 > 0, 
  x8 > 0, x9 > 0, x10 > 0, x11 > 0, x12 > 0},
  {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12}
]
```

But when I have thousands of variables, how to use it?

Comment: Are you asking how to automate the input of variables without having to type each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can avoid it: You don't. Use `FindMinimum` with a good starting point, if you can. `NMinimize` usually gets horribly slow when the number of variables increases.

Regarding syntax, you can a simple trick (works for `FindMinimum` and `NMinimize`): Declare an array of variables like this:

```
xs = Array[x, 12]
```

Now `xs` contains 12 separate variables:

> {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10], x[11], 
>    x[12]}

and you can use `xs` instead of writing the same 12 variables again and again:

```
FindMinimum[
  {GoalFunction[graph, xs], cons[graph, xs, 2500], Thread[xs > 0]},
  xs]
```

This works well for small to medium sized problems (thousands of variables).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use:

```
Module[{x = x, n = 12, vars},
 vars = ToExpression[ToString[x] <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[n];
NMinimize[
 Flatten@{GoalFunction[graph, vars], cons[graph, vars, 2500], 
  Thread[vars > 0]}, vars]
]
```